# '95 Honda Accord random/sudden electrical failures

Tags: honda, electrical, troubleshooting, accord

I noticed a few things not working, one at a time, as I tried to use them. One, the rear defroster switch on the dassh quit. Two, the PULL feature on the wiper stick on the column for the window washer quit. Three, the INTermittent setting for the wipers quit (but LO and HIGH work fine) and Four, the "RESIDUAL" power (radio, windows, etc.) after the the key is turned off quit. They're pretty random to me so I'm really hoping it's a fuse or something simple like that. Any ideas?

Comment: So do the things start working again after some time? or are they all now non-functional?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the age of your vehicle you will need to take the effect of corrosion into account as well as the possibility of a loose connection. Using a wiring diagram, a check over of the supply and earth wiring is required of the controls that are failing.